# Robotium installation

Tags: android, testing, robotium, gui-testing

i am trying to install and use "Robotium" Gui test tool for android, i am following the steps here: http://robotium.com/pages/installation
when i tried to do this step : 
"Start Eclipse and go to: Help > Install New Software. Enter "...//recorder.robotium.com/updates" "
i get an this error: 
"Unable to read repository at http://recorder.robotium.com/updates/content.xml."
i tried the same steps on another machine and it works!, what could be the problem?

thanks

Comment: For Robotium automation test, I used to reference this website : https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started How about try this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
try using "**https**" instead of "**http**".

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer behind a proxy? That could be the reason why your not allowed to access the URL.